# How to change display position of action bar overflow menu in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

Can anybody tell me how to change the display position of the action bar overflow menu in android? In my application there is an image button. If the user clicks the image button I want to display the action bar overflow menu below the image button. Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the user interface that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do that yourself, perhaps with a [`PopupMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html).

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view /*anchor view for this popup*/);
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.some_menu_resource);

/* in the onClick listener of the anchor view */
popupMenu.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `action bar Overflow menu` like say your_menu.xml in `menu` folder.

and do changes in **`Manifest`** file as well. Click [Split Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar)

```
<activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >// for API >=11
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS" // support for >=8
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
```

And Menu is like below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/button" android:title="@string/menu_option" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/action1" android:title="@string/menu_action1" />
            <item android:id="@+id/action2" android:title="@string/menu_action2" />
            <item android:id="@+id/action3" android:title="@string/menu_action3" />
            <item android:id="@+id/action4" android:title="@string/menu_action4" />
            <item android:id="@+id/action5" android:title="@string/menu_action5"/>

        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

If will behave like if there is space in `action bar`, when you will click on `ImageButton` then Overflow menu will below that button.

If there is no space in the `Action bar` then, it will show in bottom. And if you will click on `ImageButton` then Overflow menu will open on the top of Button.